# Is there any way I can Detect Decimal point while using recursion Function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I want to know **(number of each value / total number)**

let me explain with my image file .. it's hard to describe

[image]

This is **Table2** in my data, and i want know how much each number occupy out of total number

ex)

there are two 1.5 out of 20row -> 1/10 =(0.1)
and there are four 3.o out of 20 row -> 1/5 =(0.2)

like this.. so i wrote code like this

```
freq2<-rep(0,10) # to make space

for (i in 1:10) {
freq2[i]<-length(table2$xbar2.i.[table2$xbar2.i.==i])
}
```

let me explain my code, i made freq2 to make space for count frequency
and use recursion function to count each number(1.5,2.0...etc)

but i realized that recursion function can detect decimal point like
1.5 2.5 ....

is there any different, or more clever way to achieve my goal?

to make clear, my goal is to know how much each number exist out of total number

ex) 1.5 ->2/20
3.0 ->4/20,

or if this goal is difficult, just know how much each number exist 1.5 -> 2 
3.0 -> 4

thanks for reading ..!
i  appreciate your help!

Comment: Don't post data as images, post the output of `dput(table2)`, please.

Comment: you are looking for `prop.table(table(dat$xbar2.i.))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R only, here are two ways of doing what you are asking.

Since you have posted data in a wrong format, I have made up a data frame.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(xbar2.i = rep((2:6)/2, times = sample(5, 5, TRUE)))
```

And now for the code.

```
tapply(dat$xbar2.i, dat$xbar2.i, FUN = length)/length(dat$xbar2.i)
#        1       1.5         2       2.5         3 
#0.1428571 0.1428571 0.2142857 0.3571429 0.1428571

ave(dat$xbar2.i, dat$xbar2.i, FUN = length)/length(dat$xbar2.i)
```

Comment: thank you so much! it really works ! i should learn  tapply function more!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `dplyr`

```
k <- nrow(Table2)
freq2 <- Table2 %>%
         group_by(xbar2.i.) %>%
         summarise(Counts = n()) %>%
         ungroup() %>%
         mutate(Prop = Counts/k)
```

I think that's what you are after?

Comment: thanks for answer ! but it dosen't work .. actually, especially  %>% isn't work

Comment: you need to download `dplyr` package and load it.

Answer (score 1):

Read `help("prop.table")`. In that help page, though the description of the function is at best terse, its title says it all:

> Express Table Entries as Fraction of Marginal Table

So the following will do what you want.

```
 prop.table(table(dat$xbar2.i.))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: thanks for answer! actually prop.table works as calculate how much each values occupied out of total sum, i want to check how mcuh each values occupy out of total number , it's bit different !!

Comment: Actually, the prop.table if taken into consideration on its own, does what you just explained. But i used table () then used peop.table () to do exactly what you nedd